# Mega Menu dropdown works only in home page

Tags: magento-1.9, css

The **mega menu** works right in homepage, but when a customer searches for a product, it doesn't drop down.

[image: megamenu problem]

As you can see the menu highlights green but it should drop down to this

[image: megamenu working correctly]

I change the css for the z-index to 9999999 as advised in the Algolia forums but this didn't work. Any ideas guys as I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this property in your **css**:

```
.nav-container {
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you, which css file do I add this to? the megamenu or the algolia?

Comment: As you want, the best is in `local.css` or `custom.css`

Comment: You found it ?.

Comment: no not found it lol.  I tried it in the .css when i inspected it but its throwing up a long file name for the .css which I presume is because its minified in the back end.

Comment: Go to `skin/frontend/your package name/your theme name/css/style.css` or `custom.css` or `local.css`

Comment: Thank you I noticed that styles file yesterday but was unsure whether to edit it. I have added in the code at the end of the file and it brings it up but now I 'm faced with the issue of the menu constantly being there when a customer searches. Any ideas?

Comment: Disable cache, create a custom.css then add my code inside, enable cache

Comment: I found the custom.css file, I disabled cache added the code to the bottom using sublime 2, then uploaded it back through ftp. Then went back to back end and enabled cache. I'm still faced with the problem that when a customer types in the search box the megamenu still shows.

Comment: Try to clear the cache